# unzip but extract only certain fileds using unix

Tags: linux, unix, gzip

I have a large text file 5-6 gigs 61,213,301 lines. it is in a comma delimited state.

```
field1,field2,,,field5,,,field8...
```

Since I don't want to extract the whole thing to a csv (more like I can't). I am trying to extract certain lines such as field2 = ABC.

I am currently extracting all to a new file

```
gzip -dc 20130516.ticks.gz | cut -d, -f2,17,18,20-36  > ~/test/20130516.file
```

Is there a way to extract just lines with field2=ABC or extract it from 20130516.file with only field2=ABC ?

Comment: `grep '[^,]*,ABC,'`? Or use Awk, that's probably prettier (it can do the `cut` as well in a readable way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
gzip -dc 20130516.ticks.gz | awk -F, '$2 == "ABC"' > output.csv
```